# Unity, displaying laps with the GUI Text Area

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, textarea

I'm relatively new to programming and doing a simple racing game for a school assignment. I've never worked with Unity or C# before and I've encountered a problem that I would really appreciate if someone could help me with.

So I'm displaying the time and the laps with a GUI Text Area, which is working fine. But I also want the laps to increase as the car reaches my checkpoint, however, it's not working. When I'm playing the game, it still says "Laps: 0" in the GUI Text Area when I hit the checkpoint, even though it should say "Laps: 1".

I think that maybe I have to do something in void Update() but I don't know what. I've already tried a lot of different things but so far, nothing works.

```
public float timeLeft = 150f;
public int laps = 0;

void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
}

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.TextArea (new Rect (10, 10, 150, 20), "Time left: " + timeLeft + "\nLaps: " + laps);
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Checkpoint")
    {
        laps = laps + 1;
    }
}
```

Hopefully, someone more knowledgeable than me will be able to help with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the collision with the trigger is really happening.

The triggers and collisions only happen if:

- At least one of the objects have a rigidbody attached
- Both objects
  need to have a Collider attached;
- The checkpoint collider needs to have the "isTrigger" checked to be a trigger and gets the
  OnTriggetEnter working
- If both collider is convex Mesh collider, they can
  have problems checking collisions (and performance)

Unity Doc:

> This message is sent to the trigger collider and the rigidbody (or the
>   collider if there is no rigidbody) that touches the trigger. Notes:
>   Trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a
>   rigidbody attached...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the collison works because I just realized that something actually happens when I hit the checkpoint. My GUI Text Area still says "Laps: 0" but underneath that, you can see another, much fainter text that says "Laps: 1" and I really have no idea why. Ugh, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Can you use Debug.Log to see the behaviour of "laps" ?
If you start with another value, "laps" is still zero on screen?

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of this script in the game? that would explain the "faint" version as it would be drawing twice.